# Selenium: Mouse cursor (pointer) not changing its position

Tags: selenium, action

I have to move mouse cursor (pointer) to a specific element and then have to click on that element. I have written below code but it is not helping. Although I can see cursor type (image) is changing but it is not changing its position.

Please help. below is my code:

```
Utilities.waitFor(2000);            
objActions.moveToElement(questionList.get(i)).build().perform();
Utilities.waitFor(500);
objActions.click().perform();
Utilities.waitFor(500);
```

Comment: what is `questionList.get(i)`? where do you define that list?

Comment: it is a list of webelements. List<WebElement>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium move mouse cursor to element not work in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763112/selenium-move-mouse-cursor-to-element-not-work-in-firefox)

Comment: Refer [this](http://learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked:

```
Utilities.waitFor(2000);            
objActions.moveToElement(questionList.get(i)).build().perform();
Utilities.waitFor(500);
objActions.click().build().perform();
Utilities.waitFor(500);
```